# Custom design of a popup in wpf using c# (telerik )

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, popup

I am showing  an pop up in a button click event> I have kept a custom user control inside that popup and so whenever the pop is being shown taht custom usercontrol will be displayed.But now i need to modify the custom control .
Current custom control inside popup looks like below

[image]

but i need the corner to be look like the below image.. How to do it.? I need that sharp corner in my control and i need that sharp corner point whenever the popup been shown

[image]

bolow the code of the button and its popup

```
 <telerik:RadButton Name="btnH" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="444,56,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="23" Height="23" BorderThickness="6" BorderBrush="#4E4E4E" Click="btnH_Click" >
            <Image Source="Images/help.png" />
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <Popup PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Mouse" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" x:Name="TooltipPopup" >
            <Border Background="AntiqueWhite" CornerRadius="0" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Margin="1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <local:UCToolTip></local:UCToolTip>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in XAML:

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Orange">
        <!--Your content here-->
    </Grid>
    <Polygon Grid.Row="1"
        Points="0,0 15,0, 0,30" Stroke="Orange" Fill="Orange" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: :How to remove that black background.I am not able remove that background of usercontrol :(

Comment: @dahsra The black background in my image is from the Visual Studio XAML designer, the control is in fact transparent. UserControls have a transparent background by default. You must have set the background to black somewhere..

Comment: yes if i set that background in XAML it still shows the backgroundcontrol

Comment: @dahsra What happens if you remove the AntiqueWhite border background?

Comment: check here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771493/usercontrol-background-color-not-changes-even-after-setting-to-transperent-in-wp

Comment: @dahsra Remove `Background="AntiqueWhite"` from the `Border` control in the popup

Answer (score 1):

In your control for the tooltip, you can use a Grid to draw two things on top of each other.

The first, a Canvas with a custom PathGeometry of the shape you want, this is a good reasource:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393(v=vs.100).aspx

Then, make the background transparent with what you currently have and have it occupy the same cell in the Grid, so it appears on top of the shape.