# Usercontrol background color not changes even after setting to transperent in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Hi i have designed a usercontrol for using as an pop up and i have set the usercontrol background property as transperent but the background is not getting transperent 
[image]

I need that light orange to be transparent

and here is my xaml code of user control

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" x:Class="WPFTest.UCToolTip" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Height="231.493" Width="362.075"
         Background="Transparent"  >
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Hyperlink}">
                 <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextDecorations" Value="{x:Null}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Background="Orange" Margin="0,0,0,33">
        <!--Your content here-->
    </Grid>
    <Polygon
    Points="0,0 15,0, 0,30" Stroke="Orange" Fill="Orange" Margin="0,198,0,1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The background colour is not set within the XAML you have included in your answer, it is set by another element higher up the visual tree

Comment: Yaeh its user controls size,It cant be reduced further .If reduces the usercontrol border to grid size then polygon will mot nbe visible,the area other than polygon occupied was in that color :(

Comment: You need to remove `Background="AntiqueWhite"` from the parent control

Comment: I havenot set it anywhere na ..?? WHere you asking from remove?

Comment: Search your project for "AntiqueWhite"

Comment: Thanks mate it was in the popup design :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109824/discussion-between-dahsra-and-glen-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're using the `Grid` incorrectly. You need to specify which row the items are in, and once you do that, you don't need all those margins. And your first row needs to have Height="Auto" so it expands to fit the content within it.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="10,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0"  Background="Orange" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
            <Label>My Content</Label>
        </Grid>
        <Polygon 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Points="0,0 15,0, 0,30" 
            Stroke="Orange" 
            Fill="Orange" 
            Margin="0,0,0,1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: He wants to make the outside area transparent, not change the opacity of the orange area

Comment: @GlenThomas Good point, I didn't look at the points in the Polygon.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is how to make the control transparent

Comment: @GlenThomas Copy and paste his code into a test project. Try it. Then try my version.

Comment: So his XAML doesn't provide a control with transparent background (not-including the orange area)?

Comment: @GlenThomas Copy and paste his code into a test project. Run it. See what it looks like. If you have not run his code as he posted it, it's time for you to stop telling me what it does, because I have run it and I know what it does.

Comment: I wrote that code in another [one of his questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766185/custom-design-of-a-popup-in-wpf-using-c-sharp-telerik/36768066?noredirect=1#comment61120256_36768066), so I know what it does bro.

Comment: @GlenThomas Did you notice that he removed the `Grid.Row` attribute from the Polygon, bro?

Comment: I did not, but it still doesn't answer the question "I need that light orange to be transparent" :D

Comment: @GlenThomas Hey, bro. He's saying he's just seeing a big orange box, bro. He's got a big orange box with no triangle, bro. He *assumes* the problem is transparency. Can you dig it? The reason it's a big orange box is that he broke the XAML so the box and the triangle are superimposed.

Comment: No bro, you misunderstood the question. He has included a picture of the problem bro. He wants to remove the light colour from around the edge bro.

Comment: @GlenThomas He posted code that produces a big orange box with no triangle (you still haven't tried the code as he posted it, have you? Clipboard broken, eh?). He thinks there should be a triangle and talks about transparency. So I think "hey, maybe the problem in his code is the problem in the code he posted". If he broke the XAML when he put it in the question but it's not broken in his application, then yeah -- that's not the issue. If you have such strong proprietary feelings about this guy, flag my answer for deletion. Maybe "HE'S MINE!" is an option.